# Persistent undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: methods

Persistent:   undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Made many attempts to resolve this 
And found lots of support articles but still stumped

Error:

```
  undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Code:
require 'rubygems'

require 'watir-webdriver'
@browser.link(:href => ‘https://chaseonlineq2.chase.com/MyAccounts.aspx?jp_ltg=header’).exist?

HTML

    < Back to my Chase account

Help is greatly appreciated